react-complex-tree build failed , how to solve it
While i build react-complex-tree from source code
I got error message
"Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' "
src/environmentActions/EnvironmentActionsProvider.tsx:260:7
src/treeActions/TreeActionsProvider.tsx:100:7

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
   src/environmentActions/EnvironmentActionsProvider.tsx(260,7): error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.



   src/treeActions/TreeActionsProvider.tsx(100,7): error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
ERROR: "build:esm" exited with 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.

Is there any body got the same problem?
how to fix this error?
after execute command : yarn build
I got the error message above

It's probably a type error, where an element should of type ReactNode but no type or unknown has been given to it. I would check these two lines and add correct type on it.
